# I can't get redirecttoaction to work in asp.net mvc after receiving data from flash

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, redirect

I'm building an action that basically handles receiving post data from a flash app,

I have no problem receiving the data.

after that, it should redirect to another controller/action

I tried Redirect, RedirectToRoute, none of them worked.

here is my code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public RedirectToRouteResult Draw(FormCollection form)
{
    string bitmapDataString = Request.Params["someimagedata"];
    byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(bitmapDataString);
    File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Images/abc.jpg"),  
    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Participant");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirects are the job of the client (browser). You're simply telling the browser that you would like it to redirect. I don't know anything about flash but note that these redirects don't work with Ajax requests either. I know that's not a full answer but may send you in the right direction while you're waiting on someone with some flash experience.

Comment: thanks BZink. the solution is to have the flash app handle the redirect after post.